# How to add wifi credentials to wpa_supplicant using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, linux, headless

I want to add Wifi credential to `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`. (debian linux) using Node.js

The configuration file looks like

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=US

network={
    ssid="homewifi"
    psk="homepassword"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

and I want to add another network, like

```
ssid="anotherwifi"
psk="anotherpsk"
```

**1. How to add network using Node.js code?**

```
//maybe like this?
var original = exec("sudo cat wpa_supplicant.conf");
var new_network = {ssid: "anotherwifi", psk: "anotherpsk"};
exec("sudo save ? original + network?)
```

**2. Is that key_mgmt in network config, is this essential key? How do If I don't know?**

(In fact,  I want to save wifi credentials to headless iot device, using wifi access point - user send information to device via webserver)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a sample code for your reference, I hope to help you.

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
const async = require('async');

const SSID = "MyWifiAP";
const PSK = "12345678";

exec('wpa_cli add_network', function(error, stdout, stderr) 
{
    if(error !== null) {
        console.log('error: ' + error);
    }
    else {
        let net_id = stdout.substr((stdout.indexOf('wlan') + 7)).trim();

        async.series([
            function(callback) {
                exec('wpa_cli set_network ' + net_id + ' ssid \'\"' + SSID + '\"\'', function(error, stdout) 
                {
                    if(error) {
                        console.error(error);                       
                    }
                    else {                      
                        console.log('SSID result: ' + stdout);
                        callback();
                    }                   
                });
            },
            function(callback) {
                exec('wpa_cli set_network ' + net_id + ' psk \'\"' + PSK + '\"\'', function(error, stdout) 
                {
                    if(error) {
                        console.error(error);                       
                    }
                    else {                      
                        console.log('PSK result: ' + stdout);
                        callback();
                    }                   
                });
            },
            function(callback) {
                exec('wpa_cli save_config', function(error, stdout) 
                {
                    if(error) {
                        console.error(error);                       
                    }
                    else {                      
                        console.log('select_network result: ' + stdout);
                        callback();
                    }                   
                });
            }
        ], function(errs, results) {
            if(errs) throw errs;    // errs = [err1, err2, err3]
            console.log('results: ' + results);   // results = [result1, result2, result3]
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require('child_process').exec(`wpa_passphrase ${sid} ${pass}`,(err, stdout, stderr) => {
 const hash = stdout;
    fs.readFile(`./wpa_supplicant.conf`, function(err, buf) {
     var data=buf.toString().trim();
                 const set=`\n${hash}

                 `

                 fs.writeFile(`/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`, data+set, (err) => {
                                  if (err) console.log(err);
                                  try{
                                  ws.send(`ok wpa_supplicant.conf:${data}\n${set}`)

                                  }catch(err){

                                  }
                });
    });

    });
```